# Edit the paragraph that Google searches show for your website

Tags: html, seo

I'm wondering how to edit the paragraph which Google shows in its search results for your website.

[image: (I can't post the image, so there's the link to what I mean.)]

Is there a certain html tag that I would need to do to edit this? I'm having trouble finding an answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Google themselves, http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624#1:

> The description attribute within the  tag is a good way to provide a concise, human-readable summary of each page’s content. Google will sometimes use the meta description of a page in search results snippets, if we think it gives users a more accurate description than would be possible purely from the on-page content. Accurate meta descriptions can help improve your clickthrough; here are some guidelines for properly using the meta description.

Therefor, use the `<meta>` but it is not given if or when Google will use it.

Comment: You're welcome. And good luck with getting Google to use your `<meta>` description. It can be quite a headache but don't loose hope. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's called `meta` tag which you can keep between the `<head>` tags

```
<meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description. This will often show up in search results.">
```

The value assigned for `content` will be displayed as description.

Answer (score 0):

This is all because of magic of meta tags, See this article to understand more
http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2067564/How-To-Use-HTML-Meta-Tags